# Ajax / Load Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

At present I have a small web-form that loads AJAXed data really nicely from a drop down menu:

```
<select name="showcode" id="showcode">
<option value="1"> First Name</option>
<option value="2"> Last Name</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do is create the action from a text link such as:

```
<a href="javascript:showcode(1);">First Name</a>
<a href="javascript:showcode(2);">Last Name</a>
```

I don't know how to change the **.change(function() {** JS to correctly perform an action onclick event to make this happen. Below is the JS part. Any thoughts / help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#showcode").change(function() { 

var usr = $("#showcode").val();

$("#getassociatedprojects").html('Retrieving..');

$.ajax
({  
type: "POST",  
url: "/client-stories/data.php",  
data: "showcode="+ usr,  
success: function(msg)

{  
$("#getassociatedprojects").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
{  $(this).html(msg); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.

Assigned a ***rel*** and ***class*** to the `<a href>`

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="topic" rel="1">First Name</a>
```

Then changed the Javascript call in to:

```
$('a.topic').click(function() {
var usr = $(this).attr('rel');
```

Voila. It worked. :)